# Difficult to reorder sites on Android App

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app, communities-list

When editing the "Your Sites" list on the Android app, the handles on the left are extremely difficult to drag, which is necessary to reorder them. They send to be further right than I would expect, basically centered on the left edge of my screen.

Unless I touch the perfect area I find that it ends up getting interpreted as sliding the left navigation drawer.

I am encountering this issue on a Droid MAXX with Android version 4.4.4.

**Edit:** here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

[image: Reordering handles on left edge of screen.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page has bothered me for a long time. The trick is you can long click on the rows to enable the drag and drop mode, in addition to doing that pixel-perfect click on the icon you mention. This is actually the primary action mode of this page, I have no idea how to make that more noticeable on the device though :(

Comment: Well, I feel a little silly for not figuring that out.  I suppose the fact that the handles were there at all is what through me off.  If the sites were in boxes, a little more partitioned off (instead of effectively bulleted by the drag handles) I may have tried that.  Regardless, this at least addresses the frustration if not the visual confusion.  Thank you!

Comment: @thesquaregroot yeah I'm gonna play with this a bit. It's bothered me for a while, there's not any affordance right now. If you or anyone else has any more suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: My only other thought is that you might be able to use shadows to your advantage to make the elements look a little more physically reorder-able.  The way the boxes for different sites on the profile page look seems a little more drag-and-drop-able to me.  I think the context of having already hit `EDIT` and not having the handles on the left will especially lend to that interpretation.

Comment: Comparing to Google Keep, it uses card view. In addition of that (the shadow), the card also provides a visual indicator when the user press & hold the card (ripple), and dragging it while it's selected (darker background). Perhaps that can help.

Comment: This is still the case. Can you nudge the handles to the right by a few pixels please?