# Question not available after posting

Tags: bug, android-app

Immediately after posting [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271711/difficult-to-reorder-sites-on-android-app) I saw this error message:

[image: The question is not available, it may have been deleted.]

I hit cancel and went back to the home for Meta Stack Exchange and saw my question. However, I was unable to see it for maybe 4 or 5 minutes (seeing that error every time).

It eventually started working but it was obviously fairly surprising to have this happen. Also, I believe I have seen this in the past but didn't have the foresight to take a screenshot or commit the exact error message to memory.

My device is a Droid MAXX with Android 4.4.4.

**Edit:** somewhat ironically, as I posted this the following happened:

[image: Loading the question failed. Retry button.]

I attempted retrying multiple times to no avail, found the question again, and continued to see the same error for maybe a minute or two, trying periodically.

Comment: This is a really annoying caching issue. Basically, our read calls (like loading a post) are hitting a readonly DB replica that can be a few min behind the master DB which our write calls (like making a post use) -- But, that create-post API endpoint returns a `Question` model that we should be using to immediately display your post, and the view you see after creating the post should consume that.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Interesting; that makes a lot of sense.  And that solution would at least avoid the surprise of the failed automatic redirect to the question.  I imagine it would still be possible to see the error by leaving the question right after posting and clicking on it again right afterward (maybe that returned `Question` object could be cached in the app?) but that would probably be a very rare use-case.

Comment: You'd also be able to see it by just pulling to refresh on the question. It sounds like that step of using the returned question model to render the view isn't working though, I'll look into that.